# Fitting zero inflated right truncated negative binomial distribution

Tags: distributions, estimation, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I have a dataset that is bounded above by 2000 (physically not possible to have larger than 2000 values). Is there a way, in R,  to fit a zero inflated, upper bounded negative binomial distribution to such data? I also like to test for the goodness of fit.